# git svn not updating all branches when using revision range

Tags: git, svn, version-control, git-svn

I'm seeing some really odd behavior in git svn where it isn't updating all branches when passing in revision ranges.

My repo is HUGE, so I'm converting in 5k revision chunks. An example of the commands is below.

```
git svn clone --trunk=/trunk --branches=/branches --authors-file=authors.txt -r 75000:80000 https://svn.prod.oldcompany.com/repo/backend backend_conversion
git svn fetch 80000:85000
git svn fetch 85000:90000
git svn fetch 90000:HEAD
```

Most of my branches do get all of their history and revisions converted, but trunk for example only picks up the first revision range (trunk in svn, it's master in git). All other revisions are missing. I've tried resetting HEAD and re-syncing, but git svn won't pick up the later revisions on trunk. I'm starting to think it is because we at one point did have a master branch in svn under /branches/master, but I don't see why it would really make a difference due to the difference in refs for branches and trunk. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who views this in the future: drop git svn and just use subgit to convert your repos. Much easier, faster, and the engineering team behind the project is incredibly helpful, and you can do one time conversions for free. The paid mirroring functionality is really amazing and worth the cost if you do need to do mirroring as well.